# Wordpress get_option() on AJAX issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having some issues with the `get_option` method in Wordpress.

I'm running a WooCommerce website and for the `currency symbol position` is set to "Right with space". In the wp_options table the `option_name` "woocommerce_currency_pos" is correctly set to "right_space".

When viewing products on the normal website, all works well, the currency code is displayed on the right and the option value is coming back correct.

The issue however is that we use a little JS function to show the cart (`mini_cart.php`) in a lightbox and the code that is returned shows the currency code on the left.

After a bit of debugging I found the method `get_woocommerce_price_format` and the first line here is: `$currency_pos = get_option( 'woocommerce_currency_pos' );`

So this is just a default function to get the value of the stated `option_name` from the options table. This however returns "left" in this Ajax call.

I can't figure out how on earth, this is returning a different value than that in the database.

Obvious potential issues:

- Ajax is calling the wrong domain/website - But this is not happening, it is in the same project, the same code. Changes to the code reflect fine (a `die($currency_pos)` returns the string)
- It's pulling from another database - There is only 1 for the project and 1 set of config settings, so it's almost impossible that it's getting this data from elsewhere (I only have 1 project with WooCommerce).

What could this weird issue be?

p.s. 
The AJAX is called via `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

This is the full function, it is not part of a class or anything

```
/**
 * Get the price format depending on the currency position
 *
 * @return string
 */
function get_woocommerce_price_format ()
{
    $currency_pos = get_option('woocommerce_currency_pos');

    switch ($currency_pos) {
    case 'left' :
        $format = '%1$s%2$s';
        break;
    case 'right' :
        $format = '%2$s%1$s';
        break;
    case 'left_space' :
        $format = '%1$s&nbsp;%2$s';
        break;
    case 'right_space' :
        $format = '%2$s&nbsp;%1$s';
        break;
    }

    //$format = '%2$s&nbsp;%1$s';

    return apply_filters('woocommerce_price_format', $format, $currency_pos);
}
```

Comment: Can I have look at that issue on live ?

Comment: (un)fortunately the site is not live yet.

Comment: Is there any way that I can see that ?

Comment: at first look, it can be a cache issue, if its not, please check Your database to make sure there is only one option with that name in the Options table.

Comment: I did a search in the whole database and there is only 1 record for `woocommerce_currency_pos`, in the options table. Otherwise there are no duplicates in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for anyone that might need this in the future.

Woocommerce overrides the `get_option()` method with this line:
`add_filter('option_woocommerce_currency_pos', array($this, 'filter_currency_position_option'));`

Which then calls `filter_currency_position_option`

The first few lines of this method are:

```
function filter_currency_position_option($value){
    global $pagenow;

    if( ( is_ajax() || ( $pagenow == 'post-new.php' && isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'shop_order' ) ) && isset( $_COOKIE[ '_wcml_order_currency' ] ) ){
        $currency_code = $_COOKIE[ '_wcml_order_currency' ];
```

W-T-F

Okay, so it stores the currency position in a cookie for AJAX visits... I'm not sure if I can agree with this, but at least now I know.

Hope this will help someone else.